# Switch String Position Using Regular Expression (RegEx) in Notepad++

Tags: c, regex, grep, notepad++

I have the following pattern in `C` code:

```c
#if defined (_MSC_VER)
    double CC[16] __declspec(align(64)) = {0};
#else
    double CC[16] __attribute__ ((aligned (64))) = {0};
#endif
```

This is an error since it should be `__declspec(align(64)) double CC[16] = {0};`.

I would like to fix it in many files using Regular Expression. I'd be happy if the expressions will be in a format which is compatible with `Notepad++`.

So what I need is something to capture the following items:

1. `double CC[ <dontCare> ]` - Something which starts with a letter (Not to capture the beginning of the line which is either tabs or spaces) until it sees `__declspec` (Mind the space before `__declspec`).
2. Something that begins with `__declspec` and ends with `))`.
3. Everything after `))` until and including `;`.

Then I want to put them in the right order: `<2nd Item> <1st Item><3rd Item>` (Min the space betwen the 1st item and the 2nd).

The solution should be robust as sometimes the case is:

```
#if defined (_MSC_VER) && !defined(__clang__)
    double pU[3*4*K_MAX_STACK] __declspec(align(64));
#else
    double pU[3*4*K_MAX_STACK] __attribute__ ((aligned (64)));
#endif
```

I tried something at https://regex101.com/r/xzUcAt/1 with little (No!) success.

**Remark**:
I encountered this since [I found a bug](https://github.com/giaf/blasfeo/issues/120#issuecomment-623178296) in [BLASFeo](https://github.com/giaf/blasfeo) (Open source BLAS Library for small matrices) which I want to assist solving.

#### Solution

Based on the answer by @[CasNouwens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2738980/cas-nouwens) which did 99% of the work I came up with:

```
\b(.*?])\s(__declspec.+?\)\))(.*?;)
```

The solution is available at https://regex101.com/r/xzUcAt/10.

- `\b` - Captures everything until the beginning of a new word.
- `(.*?])` - Captures any character until the first `]`. Save it as `$1`.
- `\s` - Captures any spaces or any *White Space* (Tabs, etc...).
- `(__declspec.+?\)\))` - Captures any set of characters which starts with `__declspec` and ends with the first `))`. Save it as `$2`.
- `(.*?;)` - Captures everything (*White Spaces* included) until the first `;`. Saves it as `$3`.

The the new string is given by `$2 $1$3`.

This is also worked perfectly with [grepWin](https://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this Regex and see if it works for you?

```
\b(.*?)(\s__declspec.+?\)\))(.*?;)
```

https://regex101.com/r/xzUcAt/6

- The first group collects the declaration of the double including anything inside it's square brackets. ex: `double CC[16]`
- The second group collects from `__declspec` up to and including both closing parentheses `))`, example:  `__declspec(align(64))` (note, it collects the space before `__declspec` too)
- The third group collects everything after those two closing brackets up to and including a semi-colon `;`. ex:  `= {0};`

Using the Regex101 replace function with: `$2 $1$3` it results in what you are requesting.

Let me know if it helped or if something needs explaining.

**Note:** The final Regex that was used by OP was:

```
\b(.+?)\s(__declspec.+?\)\))(.*?;)
```

Comment: It looks good. The only thing, is it captures ` __decl...`. Namely with the leading space. Could we make it not capture it?

Comment: It seems I only need to remove `/s`, is that right?

Comment: Then the space is going to the 1st capture (Which I want without training spaces as well).

Comment: OK, I tried this: `\b(.+?)\s(__declspec.+?\)\))(.*?;)` and it seems to work! Saved as https://regex101.com/r/xzUcAt/8. Marking your answer.